# Swift: How to make sure that code is not optimized out?

Tags: swift, compiler-optimization, volatile

I want to zero-out the contents of an `UnsafeMutablePointer` in Swift.

In C you usually have something like this:

```
void freeSecure(void *buffer, uint64_t size) {
    // Create volatile pointer to make sure that the code won't be optimized away
    volatile uint8_t *ptr = buffer;
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < size; i++) ptr[i] = 0x00;
    free(buffer);
}
```

How can I achieve the same thing in Swift?

```
// Is extension of `UnsafeMutablePointer`
public func KC_dealloc(allocated: Int) {
    if num == 0 {
        self.destroy()
        self.dealloc(allocated)
        return
    }

    let byteCount = sizeof(Memory) * allocated
    let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(self) // volatile???
    for var i = 0; i < byteCount; i++ {
        ptr[i] = 0x00
    }
    self.destroy()
    self.dealloc(allocated)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this?

Comment: This is my actual code, but I don't know if it really zeroes out the data or if it deletes the part because the data won't be read anymore... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I asked the same question in the Apple-developer-forum and some guy there pointed me to the `memset_s`-function which does what I want.

So my Swift-code should look like this:

```
// Is extension of `UnsafeMutablePointer`
public func KC_dealloc(allocated: Int) {
    if num == 0 {
        self.destroy()
        self.dealloc(allocated)
        return
    }

    let byteCount = sizeof(Memory) * allocated
    let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(self) // volatile???
    memset_s(ptr, byteCount, 0x00, byteCount) // Defined in C11
    self.destroy()
    self.dealloc(allocated)
}
```

Comment: What is `num`? Should it be `allocated`?

Comment: To be honest I don't know it anymore – either I meant `allocated` or it was a property of `UnsafeMutablePointer`... Sry 